# undefined variable PATHFINDER in class

Tags: php

I'm having the following problem:
When I return the variable "$haebuCMS_PATHFINDER" in an echo() out of the class directly, it works. BUT when I generate an object of the class and want to grab it from this object, it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

The Code:

Part 1 : The class -> The echo works here

```
class Pathfinder {

  public $haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;

  function __construct() {

        $motherpath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/haebuCMS";

        $haebucms_pathfinder = "/Pathfinder.php";

        $haebuCMS_PATHFINDER = $motherpath . $haebucms_pathfinder;


        echo("<br>" . $haebuCMS_INDEX . "<br>" . $haebuCMS_PATHFINDER);
  }
}
```

Part 2 : The Object -> The echo doesn't work

```
include"./Pathfinder.php";
$getPath = new Pathfinder();

function getPathfinder() {
    $getPath = new Pathfinder();
    $path = $getPath->$haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;
    echo("<br><br>Pfad : " . $path . "<br><br>");
    include($path);
    return new Pathfinder();
}
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, and accepting my bad english ;)!

habux

Comment: You need to use `$this->haebuCMS_PATHFINDER` in your constructor. Otherwise you're not assigning to the class property, you're just assigning to a local variable within that method.

Comment: ^ yepper => http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Also, when you refer to that property later outside the class, don't use a dollar sign before it. So, `$path = $getPath->haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$this->haebuCMS_PATHFINDER` in your constructor. Otherwise you're not assigning to the class property, you're just assigning to a local variable within that method.

```
class Pathfinder {

    public $haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;

    function __construct() {
        // Asssign to the public property using $this->
        $this->haebuCMS_PATHFINDER = "C:/xampp/htdocs/haebuCMS/Pathfinder.php";

    }
}
```

Also, when you refer to that property later outside the class, don't use a dollar sign before it.

```
$getPath = new Pathfinder;
// Refer to the public property without using $ before the property name
$path = $getPath->haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;
echo("<br><br>Pfad : " . $path . "<br><br>");
```

When you use `$getPath->$haebuCMS_PATHFINDER;`, it's expecting a variable `$haebuCMS_PATHFINDER` (which isn't present) to use to refer to a property dynamically.